# React/Redux - Dispatching the same action multiple times

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my react application, I have a special case of action dispatching, where I am mapping over an array, and then for each item I will dispatch an action - same action for all items.

Is there a way for me to set the state in my reducer only when the last action is dispatched?

E.g.: I want a loading state to be false when all actions are done being dispatched. But at the moment the state will be set on the first dispatched action, and the application therefore thinks, that we are done loading.

Can anyone help me out?

TIA.

Comment: add a `DONE_LOADING` action and fire that one last ?

Answer (score 0):

An option is to subtract the array length from the iterator index and supply that to the reducer, and if it's 0 then you know its the last iteration, then you set the app loading state.

```
// action creator
    arrayData.map((item,i) => {  
        const indexOffset = i + 1
        dispatch({
            type: 'APP:UPDATE_STATE',
            key: item.key,
            val: item.value,
            iteratorIndexOffset: arrayData.length - indexOffset
        })
    })

// reducer
    switch(action.type){
       case 'APP:UPDATE_STATE': 
        return {
            ...state,
            [action.key]: action.val,
            // if value is one then its the last element in the array
            appLoading: (action.iteratorIndexOffset > 0)
        }
    }
```